# RStudio Job Launcher - NFS mounting issue

Tags: kubernetes, rstudio, jobs, amazon-eks, nfs

I am trying to integrate RStudio Worbench with Kubernetes as described in the official documentation https://docs.rstudio.com/rsw/integration/launcher-kubernetes/. In step 9 the Launcher starts a Kubernetes Job. The job is successfully assigned to a pod but the pod stucks in 'ContainerCreating' status display the next events:

```
Mounting command: mount
Mounting arguments: -t nfs MY.NFS.SERVER.IP:/home/MY_USER_DIR /var/lib/kubelet/pods/SOME_UUID/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/mount0
Output: mount.nfs: Connection timed out
Warning  FailedMount  13m (x6 over 54m)     kubelet  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[mount0], unattached volumes=[kube-api-access-dllcd mount0]: timed out waiting for the condition
Warning  FailedMount  2m29s (x26 over 74m)  kubelet  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[mount0], unattached volumes=[mount0 kube-api-access-dllcd]: timed out waiting for the condition
```

**Configuration details:**

- Kubernetes is successfully installed on Amazon EKS and I am controlling the cluster from an admin EC2 instance outside the EKS cluster which I'm running NFS server and RStudio on
- I can deploy an RStudio test job only without volume mounts
- Both nfs-kernel-server service and RStudio are running
- Our RStudio users are able to launch jobs in Local mode
- The file **/etc/exports** contains:

```
    /nfsexport 127.0.0.1(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
    /home/MY_USER_DIR MY.IP.SUBNET.RANGE/16(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

- Inbound traffic to the NFS server from the Kubernetes worker nodes is allowed via port 2049

**What I have tried:**

1. Mount some folder locally on the same machine as the NFS server - that works
2. Mount using different IPs for the NFS server: localhost, public IPv4, and private IPv4 of the EC2 instance (with and without specifying the port 2049) - that did not work
3. Connect to a client machine and try to manually mount from there. Trying to mount the share on the server resulted in:

```
   mount.nfs: rpc.statd is not running but is required for 
   remote locking.
   mount.nfs: Either use '-o nolock' to keep locks local, or start statd.
   mount.nfs: mount.nfs: Operation not permitted
```

4. Trying to ping the admin instance from a worker node doesn't work even though all EKS plugins (coredns, kube-proxy, vpc-cni) are active.

**Question:** What could be the root problem causing the mounting issue? Thank you in advance!

Comment: what is your Kubernetes version?

Comment: @Bazhikov The version is 1.21

Comment: have you configured NFS Server properly and exactly how it's explained in your guide? At least I can see the difference: `I am controlling the cluster from an admin EC2 instance outside the EKS cluster which I'm running NFS server and RStudio on` and  from the guide(from step 4): `Provision an NFS server that exports the /home directory. We recommend configuring an NFS server on a machine that runs separately from RStudio Workbench and Launcher.` There are also many useful Notes you can double check

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue with RStudio job launcher. The reason for this issue was because of non-existent directory in the NFS. The home directory in the pod gets mounted to the user's home directory in the NFS.

For example if you logged into the RStudio as **user1**, the system expects a home directory for **user1** in the NFS. With the default configuration, this directory will be **/home/user1**. If this directory does not exists in NFS, the mount will fail and the command gets timed out.

The simple way to debug this issue is by manually trying to mount the directories

```
mkdir -p /tmp/home/user1
mount -v -t nfs ipaddress:/home/user1 /tmp/home/user1
```

The above command will fail if the **/home/user1** directory does not exist in the NFS. The solution is to ensure that the user home directories exist in the NFS.